# convert a list of hashes to a argument for a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash, sinatra

I have hash based arguments.

```
method1(:test=>[:arg1, :arg2 => :something])
```

I need to pass `:test` as argument to another method in the following format

from A:

```
[:arg1, {:arg2=>:something}]
```

to B:

```
method2 :arg1, :arg2=>:something
```

How can I get from A to B?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about?

```
args = {:test => [:arg1, :arg2 => :something]}
method1(args)

method2(*args[:test])
```

Comment: Thank you, I have a feeling my problem was leaving the asterisk out. I didn't think I would need to use it when passing values, only when defining arguments in the method (method 2).

Comment: By the way, in Ruby this is called the splat operator.

Answer (score 0):

If `ary = [:art1, {:arg2 => :something}]` then `method2 *ary` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have a lot of things in your hash, you could just loop on the keys and dereference them. What has to happen for this to work is:

1. you have to add the key/values in the order you want them.
2. be using 1.9 (I believe it was in 1.9 that they made it so that key ordering is retained in hashes)